# How to get the Row and Column count of a grid in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

How to get the Row and Column counts of grid in C#, just regular window control grid, not datagrid or gridview

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I thought clicking the up arrow would do it.

Comment: The up-arrow is a upvote. Please keep upvoting helpful answers. But to accept the answer you need to hit the V - like you already did here. Good! :-)

Comment: I don't know.. Perhaps it is recalculated every now and then? Check later..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried `grid.RowDefinitions.Count` and `grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count`?