# Bind to column count property of parent Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `Rectangle` style that I'm using to highlight `Grid` rows when hovering over them with the mouse pointer.

I'd like to bind the `Grid.ColumnSpan` property of the `Rectangle` to the parent `Grid` column count.  Any idea on how to do this?  Is binding to the parent `Grid` and using a converter to return the column count the best option?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MouseOverHighlightStyle" TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="4" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.3" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource MouseOverHighlightStyle}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource MouseOverHighlightStyle}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource MouseOverHighlightStyle}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource MouseOverHighlightStyle}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Have you tried `Grid.ColumDefinitions.Count`? [How to get the Row and Column count of a grid in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732837/how-to-get-the-row-and-column-count-of-a-grid-in-c)

Comment: Hmm...  My google-fu wasn't up to snuff this time...  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your Window.Resources to this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MouseOverHighlightStyle" TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="{Binding Path=ColumnDefinitions.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.3" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

There you are getting your parent (Grid in this example) ColumnDefinition.Count and set it to the columnSpan of your Rectangle. I've just tried it and its working, so let me know if it works for you too

Comment: Perfect, that's the one!  Couldn't figure out which parameter in the parent `Grid` to bind to.  Thanks! :-)

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't exactly answer your question, but you could just set the Span to something really big, so that your Rectangle always spans the entire region no matter how many columns there are. Something like:

```
<Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2147483647" /> <!-- int.MavValue -->
```

Comment: I thought about it, but it felt a bit "dirty" to me. :-)